# Using IF statement in a .click function in jQuery

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I'm trying to build a jQuery gallery and I've got a button which will shift the gallery right 600px but, because it will still shift it if the gallery is at the far left, I wanted to add an "if" statement to the function, so that if the position of the gallery was at the far left (left: 0px) it would not shift any further, but would work otherwise.

So this is what I have so far, I hope it gives an idea of what I want to do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".left").click(function(){
  if($("#gallery").right() === '0px'){
    $("#gallery").animate({left: '-=600px'});
  });
 });
});
```

This is based on the code which I know works:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".left").click(function(){
    $("#gallery").animate({left:'-=600px'});
  });
});
```

Any help would e appreciated, cheers guys.

Answer (score 0):

That would be

```
if($("#gallery").css('right') === '0px'){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well your problem, you can never reach the right side of the gallery equals to zero unless you don't consider the width of the gallery and its position in relation to the window. Therefore, it is better to change the condition from `$("#gallery").right() === '0px'` to `$("#gallery").right() < '0px'` (i.e. smaller than zero).